# Playing Mass Effect on multiple consoles

Tags: mass-effect-3, pc, mass-effect-3-multiplayer, origin, wii-u

I obtained Mass Effect 3 as a free game for the compensation for the Sim City downtime, more than a year ago. I liked ME3 quite a lot, and even played it more than SC itself. Now I still play it occasionally, as it is the only online shooter I have on the PC.

About a week ago, I bought a second-hand Wii U, with ME3 as one of the games included. I didn't play it yet (Mario Kart first of course :P), but I wondered if it's possible to share my online results between the Wii U and PC. I don't care about the single player savegame, just the online rewards. Will my earnings on the Wii U be transferred (via my Origin account) and obtained on my PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The games on each system are considered separate games and do not share unlocks.

Here is the [N7HQ](http://social.bioware.com/n7hq/home/) profile page.  You can see each system in the dropdown box.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I visited the HQ page quite often, for the tracking of certain achievements. But I never though it would be handy to click the dropdown box with my name on it :)